# Confused by what Paul Graham says about locality in his book "On Lisp"

Tags: lisp, localization

https://sep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf On page 36 Paul writes the following:

> The conditions above do not guarantee the perfect locality you get
> with purely functional code, though they do improve things somewhat.
> For example, suppose that f calls g as below:
>
> ```lisp
> (defun f (x)
>   (let ((val (g x)))
>     ; safe to modify val here?
>     ))
> ```
>
> Is it safe for f to nconc something onto val? Not if g is identity:
> then we would be modifying something originally passed as an argument
> to f itself.  So even in programs which do follow the convention, we
> may have to look beyond f if we want to modify something there.
> However, we don’t have to look as far: instead of worrying about the
> whole program, we now only have to consider the subtree beginning with
> f.

I don't understand what he means by saying that it is not safe for `f` to `nonc` if `g` is *identity*. Or I suppose I don't understand the idea that he's trying to convey in this paragraph in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's talking about side-effects of calling a function (and whether they can be avoided).

A purely functional language would not allow a call to `f(x)` to modify the value of the argument being passed to that function; but because `nconc` is *destructive*, that's exactly what would happen here if `g` was the `identity` function (as then `val` would refer to the same cons cell as the argument to `f`).

I.e. `val` would not be a value which was local to the function.